# Referencing Formatted Cells in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have a column currently sent to a format that would round the numbers to the nearest thousand. `((#,##0,_);(#,##0,))`.

I also have formulas on another sheet that would pull those numbers in.  However, they only pull in actual rather then the rounded formatted numbers.  Is there a way to remedy this?

Currently my formulas is:

```
=IFERROR(IF(OR(P$4="1120S",P$4=1120,P$4=1065),INDEX(B1HY1!$A$3:$F$300,MATCH(2,B1HY1!$F$3:$F$300,0),5),0),0)
```

Comment: format the output cells identical to the input cells?

Comment: I thought of that too.  But to make life easier whenever I need to make adjustments to the output cells It would be easier to not type in a bunch of 0's.  So I was just wondering if there's a way to pull in the rounded numbers.

Comment: Wrap the INDEX/MATCH in `ROUND(...,-3)`

Comment: That works! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `TEXT` formula to your formula,

`=TEXT(A12,"#,##0")`

You can replace the A12 with your formula